# scrollabe tab view in react-native native base

Tags: ios, react-native, performance-testing, native-base

I have used scrollable tab view from native base here is link [link](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#advanced-tabs-headref)

for my react native application . its performance is very slow when I press some tab from tab menu it go to that screen slowly.
 what I can do for better performance for quick screen changing. Native base scrollable tab view is same as in react-native-scrollable-tab-view 
[react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Don't forgot to import ScrollableTab in native base.  [Native base Scrollable Tab](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-advanced-headref)